# jQuery ui change button to flat style

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, flat

I would like to change a button in jQuery ui to adapt the theme of my page, manually. I managed to change the color, the font...
But I would like a flat button, like this:

[image]

My button looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to remove the shadows?

Here is the css: (jquery 1.10.3)

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
        text-align: left;
        border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
        /*background-image: none;*/
        margin-top: .5em;
        padding: .3em 1em .5em .4em;
            outline: none;
            background: #a3cb38
    }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
        float: right;
    }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button {
        /*margin: .5em .4em .5em 0;*/
        position: relative;
            top: 3px;
            left: 15px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 45px;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #ffffff;   /* couleur police bouton */
            outline: none;
            font-family:Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            background: #fed136;   /* couleur fond bouton */
            border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; 
    }
```

I'm new in jquery, there's so many button lines...

Comment: What is css of button?

Comment: check this out https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/w9m8p2tr/

Comment: ksno: I've edited my question, thx for your answer
guradio: Thx I will see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's default button border styles you are seeing, remove the border like so:

```
border:0;
```

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to use your browsers developer tools to inspect elements, you'll be able to identify styles like this easily yourself :)

Comment: Ok, it's true I doesn't thought to use it. Just firebug to see javascript bugs, but nothing for this kind of prblem! Thks again